# $http angular JS not working and not data populating on view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Controller.js"></script>


app.directive("myData", function()
{
    return {
        templateUrl: '/my-data.html'
    };

});
```

### start html (my-data.html) file code

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.gender | uppercase }}</td>
    <td>{{employee.salary | currency : '$'}}</td>
</tr>

--------------------end html----
<body ng-app="DemoAngular">
    <div ng-controller="AngularController">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <my-data></my-data>
</tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
</body>
```

added customer directive still nothing happening..
any clue?
created new customer directive
add templete URL in directive .(my-data.html)
add newly created directive in HTML main file

Comment: nothing is coming on screen only 'column' names..

Comment: What errors are showing in your JavaScript console? I'm guessing `Angularservice` isn't the only case problem you have.

Comment: for Typo my code is right but dont while added here in question its got changed with lower case not sure .....sorry about that I modified

Comment: Can you post the log of your Javascript Console and maybe also the Source Code of the rendered webpage?

Comment: added new custom directive but still having issue nothing is coming on screen

Answer (score 0):

you injected the factory with this name inside your controller

```
Angularservice
```

it should be

```
AngularService
```

Change .factory to .service please

Comment: Change from a factory to a service please

Comment: app.service("AngularService", function ($http, $log) {

     //var customservice = {};
     
     this.customservice.getalldata = function(cb) {

         $http({

             method: 'GET',
             url: 'WebService/EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployee'
         }).then(function (response) {
             cb(response.data);
             debugger;
         }, function (reason) {
             $log.log("error");
         })

     };

    // return customservice;
 });
changed still not working

Comment: Nope. Just use this.getalldata

Comment: Inside the controller AngularService.getalldata

Comment: Remove return statement inside the service too, just define the method to this.

Comment: can you please change the function inside the service in order to return a string? let's understand if the problem is really there, or if you have any issue in the api

Comment: oh you missed returns inside your function in the service too

return $http

Comment: then inside your controller do 

`AngularService.getalldata().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});`

Comment: AngularService.getalldata(function (cb) { }).then(function (data) { console.log(data); }); added but getting error 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'

Comment: remove the function inside getalldata

Comment: if you refer my service code i have function defination with callback. so if i remove i am getting error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misspelled Change

**From**

```
app.controller("Angularcontroller", function($scope,Angularservice)
```

**To**

```
app.controller("Angularcontroller", function($scope,AngularService)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several typos in your code.

First of all `Url` in your $http call should be `url`

```
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/WebService/EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployee'
})
```

Besides, module, controller and services are instantiated and declared with different names:

```
Angularservice -> AngularService
Angularcontroller -> AngularController
Demoangular -> DemoAngular
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
app.controller("Angularcontroller", [ 
                                 '$scope', 
                                 'AngularService', 
                                  function 
                                  ($scope, AngularService) {
```